# Change as an <p> text show itself every click with JavaScript using a series of quotes you have

Tags: javascript, paragraph

So that's my question, (I know it could be a very easy one but I ma completely new to JavaScript). So I have a list of quotes. I need a script that every time the user click wherever part of the window it changes the quote, based on the chronological order I want. And then when the quotes are finished restart again. So let me say as soon the user open the page I have a paragraph with quote1 than the user click everywhere and this happens: the same paragraph get the quote2.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty hard to be specific with an answer because you leave a lot of open questions.  But, conceptually here are the steps:

1. Register a click event handler so that your code gets called when the desired click happens.
2. When your click handler is called, you then need to get the DOM object of the `<p>` tag that you want to change.
3. Then, you need to fetch the next quote to display.  Presumably, you would store these in an array and you'd keep an index of what array position you are currently displaying so you can get the next one.  If you want this to work across different page loads, then you would need to store the index in a cookie so it persists to other page loads on this computer.
4. Once you have the DOM element and the quote, you just set the innerHTML property of the DOM element to insert the desired quote.

If your HTML was this:

```
<p id="theQuote">This is the first quote</p>
```

And, you want a click of this button to change the quote:

```
<button onclick="changeQuote()">Change Quote</button>
```

or if you want a click anywhere in the page, you could use this for your body tag:

```
<body onclick="changeQuote()">
```

Then, you could do so with this code:

```
var quoteIndex = 0;
var quotes = [
    "First Quote",
    "Second Quote",
    "Third Quote"
];
function changeQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    if (quoteIndex >= quotes.length) {
        quoteIndex = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("theQuote").innerHTML = quotes[quoteIndex];
}
```

If you really want a click anywhere in the page to rotate the quote (which seems unlikely to be the right design), then you can assign the click handler to the body tag instead.

Comment: He wants to click anywhere on the page and change the quote.

Comment: @ATOzTOA - that part isn't entirely clear from the question and I'd be surprised if that's really what they want because there are probably other objects on the page that use clicks.  In any case, it's no big deal to take the above outline and apply the click handler to the body object. I added some explanation for that.

Comment: Thank you for the fast and precise answer. You are great. Unfortunately this is not very helpful for me cause it include too much complicate terms for someone like me than never deal with JavaScript before. But I am sure it would be super useful to someone more expert than me. Just a quick question, you think it would be easier with jquery to explain?

Comment: @user1925934 - I gave you the simplest code example possible.   If there's something you don't understand, you can ask questions.  We can't be more specific about the code if you don't include your actual HTML.  This question doesn't get much easier with jQuery if you define the right HTML.

Answer (score 0):

What have you try?

Here i use jquery for faster code

```
var quotes = ["quote1","quote2"];
var current = 0;

function changeQuote(){
    if (current >= quotes.length) current = 0;
    document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML(quotes[current]);
    current++;
}

document.body.onclick = changeQuote;
```

Comment: There's no jQuery tag on this answer. The SO convention in that case is that you should be providing straight javascript.

Comment: @jfriend00  you to both of you guys. I understand everything you said so that's perfect. I think that Trinh make a jquery example cause I asked in my previous comment if was easier to explain with jquery so it's not is fault. Thank you guys again, really

Comment: @user1925934 - the convention here on StackOverflow is that if you want a jQuery answer, then you either tag your question with jQuery or ask for jQuery in your question.  With no mention of jQuery, answers are supposed to be plain javascript, not jQuery.  You should specify what you want in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var quotes = ["Quote 1", "Quote 2"]
    var index = 0;

    function updateQuote() {
        index = index + 1;
        if(index == quotes.length) {
            index = 0;
        }

        document.getElementById("myQuote").innerHTML = quotes[index];
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onClick="updateQuote(); return false;">
<p id="myQuote"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no jQuery tag on this answer.  The SO convention in that case is that you should be providing straight javascript.

Comment: Updated answer with straight JS.